# Python Re - Named Capture Group Too Greedy

Tags: python, regex, python-re, regex-greedy

I would like to pick up "Bar" from the following strings:

```
FooFooFoo the FooFoo the Bar Foo
FooFooFoo the FooFoo my Bar Foo
```

But the regex I wrote `(the|my) (?P<bar>.+?) Foo` seems to be too greedy and collects more text than required ([example at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Xd4PWs/2/))

***edit***: "Bar" is an exemplified string to match. In my real case scenario that could me made up of multiple words.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

I need to run this with the standard re python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that the regex engine searches for matches from left to right, and once `my` or `the` is found, the `.+?` will match as few chars other than line break chars as possible, but *as many as necessary* to complete a valid match.

You need to match all text (using `.*?`) up to the last word (that can be matched with a `\w+` pattern) before `Foo`:

```php
(the|my) .*?(?P<bar>\w+) Foo
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LtEPP/1). Another variation is to match `the` or `my` as whole words and match any text up to the closest non-whitespace char chunk before `Foo`:

```js
\b(the|my)\b.*?(?P<bar>\S+)\s+Foo
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LtEPP/2). *Details*:

- `\b(the|my)\b` - the `the` or `my` word as a whole word
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?P<bar>\S+)` -  Group "bar": one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `Foo` - a `Foo` string.

Comment: Thanks! These solutions work like a charm! Is there something I could look into in case the exemplified "Bar" string to match is made up of multiple words?

Comment: @mistyped If `Bar` is made of multiple words, you must figure out what text after `my` or `the` needs consuming in order to skip. Or, you should define the number of "words" to capture in Group "bar". You just nee to be very specific with this regex requirements.

Comment: Thank you! This is, again, helpful.